# ubuntu 20.04 on raspberry pi 4b: cannot upgrade bootloader

Tags: ubuntu, bootloader

On my (fully updated) Ubuntu 20.04 RPI 4B, I tried to use rpi-eeprom package from https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/archive/master.zip to update the 2020-04-16 bootloader

```
    # vcgencmd bootloader_version 
    Apr 16 2020 18:11:26
    version a5e1b95f320810c69441557c5f5f0a7f2460dfb8 (release)
    timestamp 1587057086

    # ./rpi-eeprom-update -d -f firmware/stable/pieeprom-2020-07-16.bin
    BCM2711 detected
    Dedicated VL805 EEPROM detected
    BOOTFS /boot
    *** INSTALLING firmware/stable/pieeprom-2020-07-16.bin  ***
    BOOTFS /boot
    EEPROM update pending. Please reboot to apply the update.
    #
```

I checked that in /boot 3 files are indeed copied:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       65 Aug  6 11:15 pieeprom.sig
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   524288 Aug  6 11:15 pieeprom.upd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    87784 Aug  6 11:15 recovery.bin
```

pieeprom.upd is a copy of pieeprom-2020-07-16.bin:

```
# cmp /boot/pieeprom.upd firmware/stable/pieeprom-2020-07-16.bin
#
```

sig file is OK:

```
# cat pieeprom.sig
88f43e537fd3e390c0447a34f0fc266b2305e32b413d0a969401518035bcac3b
# sha256sum pieeprom.upd
88f43e537fd3e390c0447a34f0fc266b2305e32b413d0a969401518035bcac3b  pieeprom.upd
#
```

BUT after cold reboot, eeprom is not modified:

```
# vcgencmd bootloader_version 
Apr 16 2020 18:11:26
version a5e1b95f320810c69441557c5f5f0a7f2460dfb8 (release)
timestamp 1587057086
```

And /boot/pieeprom.upd file is still there

Did I miss something and is there any way to find why the bootloader upgrade did not happen?

Answer (score 2):

rpi-eeprom scripts don't work on ubuntu because they fail to detect BOOTFS correctly
you don't have to install Raspbian just to update eeprom/vl805 firmware, you just have to run scripts correctly

fat partition on sd card (/dev/mmcblk0p1) is mounted to /boot on Raspbian systems, and /boot/firmware on Ubuntu
when running rpi-eeprom-update on ubuntu, it installs update files to /boot which is just a directory on rootfs and not the boot partition of your sd card

so to update EEPROM on ubuntu you need the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom.git && cd rpi-eeprom
sudo BOOTFS=/boot/firmware ./rpi-eeprom-update -a
```

you'd also need userland commands for vl805 which can be installed via libraspberrypi-bin package on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install libraspberrypi-bin
```

after reboot update would be installed